# Android: popup to reboot phone

Tags: android, reboot

I would like to produce a popup window giving the user to ability to select yes to reboot the phone. Possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible because the Intent for rebooting ([ACTION_REBOOT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_REBOOT)) is protected and can only be sent by the system.